# Make a Android application use FIPS 140-2 valiated cryptography

Tags: android, ssl, okhttp, fips, boringssl

I have client who wants our application to use [FIPS 140-2 validated cryptography](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FIPS_140-2). The app uses [Okhttp and does some HTTPS requests](http://square.github.io/okhttp/). AFAIK Android uses OpenSSL C library and [uses java wrapper javax/net/ssl](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/net/ssl/package-summary.html).

Questions:

1. How to make android Application FIPS 140 -2 Complaint?
2. Is it not android at stack(OS) level should use FIPS Compliant OpenSSL, hence all app are default  FIPS 140 -2 Compliant?
3. Or our app should use FIPS 140-2 validated cryptography and make java javax/net/ssl to use it? Feasible?
4. Is there a  FIPS 140-2 JCE library which can be pluggable to OKhttp?

Thanks

Comment: Android uses Google's own BoringSSL instead of OpenSSL, starting from Marshmallow, and they generally disable all FIPS flags, because they make OpenSSL less secure by delaying bugfixes. So you will need to compile OpenSSL yourself, and include it into your app.

Comment: @pelya have you tried OpenSSL and made javax/net/ssl use the same? any example..

Comment: What level of security(Defines by FIPS 140-2) you require in your app?

Comment: @PravinDivraniya basically the TLS/SSL crypto library needs to approved by FIPS by certifying it.  https://www.wolfssl.com/wolfSSL/fips.html

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Modified OKHTTP and OKIO code to use the WolfSSL java wrappers and made it work.

Now any https requests made will go to WolfSSL layer instead of stock android BoringSSL/OpenSSL.

Comment: Maybe it would have been to dupe your question to your other question, if answer is the same http://stackoverflow.com/a/43184135/5292302

Comment: This answer is just barely above useless. If you are going to have it as an answer, then *show* what changes were needed, don't just tell people that some unspecified modifications were needed. We could give that answer to **any** debugging question. "You have to make some changes, then it works." Is not an answer.

Comment: Could you please provide more context around what you actually did here to make this work? As mentioned above, this answer doesn't provide much value to readers